# the table view dosen't show the data in javafx

Tags: javafx, mixlib-shellout

I've made correct code but not showing the result.

Is The table  empty or hide at the end?

public class FXMLResultController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
//You shouldn't make a new TableView
//TableView Tblresult = new TableView();
//Just declare it since it's already made in the FXML file
TableView Tblresult;

@FXML
TableColumn col;
@FXML
ResultSet Rs = null;
@FXML
public ComboBox reportcombo;

@FXML
int id = 1;

@FXML
public void SelectItem(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
    ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList row=null;
    // ObservableList row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    //ListView<String> a = new ListView<String>();
    // ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
    // ResultSetMetaData row;

    id = reportcombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    String Query = null;

    switch (id) {
        case 0:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;
        case 1:
            Query = "select sum(price) from book";

            break;
        case 2:
            Query = "select count(*) as tedad,title from book group by title";

            break;
        case 3:
            Query = "select * from book()";

            break;
        case 4:
            Query = "select * from book where";

            break;
        case 5:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;
        case 6:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;
        case 7:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;
        case 8:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;
        case 9:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;
        case 10:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;
        case 11:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;

        case 12:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;
        case 13:
            Query = "select * from book";

            break;

    }

    Rs = DB_Model.Exequte_Query(Query);
    Rs.beforeFirst();
    int counter = 1;
    Tblresult.getColumns().clear();
    while (Rs.next()) {
        row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        row.add(Rs.getString(counter));
        data.add(row);
        col = new TableColumn(Rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(counter));
        Tblresult.getColumns().add(col);
        col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Object,Object>(Rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(counter)));

        counter++;
    }

    Tblresult.getItems().setAll(data);
    Tblresult.setItems(data);
    Tblresult.setVisible(true);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        System.err.println(data);

    }

}
```

}

FXML.fxml file :

Fxml file :

```
  <TableView fx:id="Tblresult" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="262.0" prefHeight="256.0" prefWidth="692.0">

  </TableView>
```

When I print the row I see the result, but not when I set it in the table.

its my all code

Comment: Did you define a cell value factory?

Comment: what's cell value factory ???

Comment: all my code is that u see

Comment: I'm guessing from the edits that you don't understand the problem.  There's a lot of duplicates of this problem.  Maybe this is a better explanation.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18653913/2855515 .  In essence, don't declare a new TableView, it's already made in the FXML file.

Comment: I edited your code to help with the explanation.  There may be more errors.  If you want us to find errors, you need a small, compile-able example.

Comment: hello.tnx for edting.codes are fine with compile.

Comment: i changed it to TableView Tblresult; still not wrorking

Comment: is there any command like setviewportview in javafx as there was in swing?